# Class Equal to Another Class

Tags: css, overflow, overlay, summary, squarespace

I am using CSS and position:absolute to force a summary title overlay feature that is not offered in Squarepace. These are issues I am having:

Setting the width to 20% for a summary containing 5 image I thought would cover the pictures completely, but there is a gap between each image overlay. Is there a way to make this equal to the with of the summary image it is sourcing from?

Secondly, I was trying to get the truncate property to cut off the text at the end of the line, but I cannot get it to take either.

This is the site I am working on: http://www.sunsetstudiosent.com at the bottom of the page.

This is the code I am currently using:

```
.sqs-block-summary-v2 .summary-content {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0px;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  background: rgba(39,39,39,0.5); /* colour of background behind the title and excerpt */
}
.summary-title-link{
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  width: 20%;
  color: rgba(249,249,249,1) !important; /* color of title links */
}
.sqs-block-summary-v2 .summary-block-setting-show-title .summary-thumbnail-container{
  margin-bottom: 0 !important; /* fix to bottom of thumbnail */
  overflow: hidden; /* hide anything that doesn't fit */
}
```

Comment: You have to add `white-space: nowrap;   
overflow: hidden;` if you want `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to work. [CSS text-overflow property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp)

Comment: The ``white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;`` worked but the ``text-overflow: ellipsis;`` did not

Comment: Did you try to add `!important` before the `;` in case these property had already been defined ?

Comment: @Charles.C Yes I did that as well.

Comment: In this case, I'm afraid this is beyond my skills to help you. (I'm still a newbie in all this...). Good luck !

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your problem disappear when you set :

```
    .summary-content {
         width: 20.2%;
     }
```

I saw that your class "sql-gallery-design-carousel-slide" have also its width set to 20.2%.

Comment: How is this possible though? 5 x 20% is 100%? Also anything about truncating the text?

Comment: Is it possible to set the class equal to the width of the class so that it however it changing it adjusts automatically?

Comment: @ThisGuy No, it's not possible, at least not in pure CSS.

Comment: What about with some javascript or jquery?

Comment: @ThisGuy  know for sure that it is possible and  not very difficult. Although I'm too new with Javascript to describe you how to do so. In my humble opinion, you really should try to modify you HTML or CSS in order to get rid of your problem. Doing such thing with Javascript is like trying to crush a fly with a hammer, it's possible but not very appropriate.   :)

Comment: This is one of the cons of working on the Squarespace platfrorm, in that you cannot really alter the HTML without running the template in developer mode, which prevents you from getting updates. So the hammer it needs to be.